# Implementing an edge search in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to implement an edge search in BigQuery in the most efficient way, following the blog post [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-performance-tips-searching-for-text-8x-faster-f9314927b8d2). Here is an illustration with two columns and three search terms how the edge search would work --

```
Search term: "tim burton lux" (split on space ==> "tim", "burton", lux")
```

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE

# "tim"
((director LIKE '%tim%') OR (country LIKE '%tim%'))

# "burton"
AND ((director LIKE '%burton%') OR (country LIKE '%burton%'))

# "lux"
AND ((director LIKE '%lux%') OR (country LIKE '%lux%'))
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fdb8b/3/0).

However, notice how absolutely dreadful the above search performance would be. For example, what if the table had 20 columns on three search terms? Is there a better way to implement the above using regex? I've been trying but having been able to combine the OR/ANDs in a more compact format.

A short-hand version of the above (not technically correct, but more efficient), would be doing something like:

```
Any column that starts with "tim", or starts with "burton",
or starts with "lux", or starts with "tim burton lux".
```

Comment: shouldn't it rather be - `director LIKE '%tim%' AND director LIKE '%burton%' AND country LIKE '%lux%'` ?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant right, but we don't know beforehand which term corresponds to which column. A user just types in anything, and we need to search across all available columns.

Comment: oh, i see  - I thought those terms coming somehow from data itself - but it is set by users- ok

Comment: when you mention 20 columns - do  you worry more about how messy code is going to be or more about efficiency? asking as it is hard to please all - so you need to set priority here I think.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant code can be as messy or long-winded as possible. Only care about performance here, as currently seeing search across columns taking 20-30s.

Comment: interesting challenge I think - will think through it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, below will not fully address your expectations, but still wanted to share this option for below criteria:

> Any column that starts with "tim", or starts with "burton",
>   or starts with "lux"

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `mytable` AS (
  SELECT 'Tim Burton' director, 'Luxembourg' country UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tim burton', 'canada' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'james cameron', 'canada' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'kirk cameron', 'usa' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'james dawson', 'france' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'sarah silverman', 'france' 
)
SELECT * FROM `mytable` t
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'(?i):"(tim|burton|lux)')
```

with (I think expected) result as

```sql
Row director    country  
1   Tim Burton  Luxembourg   
2   tim burton  canada
```

I think this addresses "20 columns" question and looks like relatively easy to be adjusted to some variations of the above criteria
From the performance prospective - hard to say (share your testing results please)  - in any case keep in mind  - this is a BigQuery which is not tailored for serving interactive UI and mostly is for analytics - but keep trying ... :o)

Comment: I had the feeling that TO_JSON_STRING would work here :) The other option is FORMAT with `%t`, but I think that TO_JSON_STRING will likely have better performance.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better approach, just need to AND the columns better for each word, so that only "tim burton luxembourg" shows. But the above approach works nicely. # of where clauses = number of search terms and not search terms x num columns

Comment: Great, consider voting up if not yet :o)